# ¿Cómo implementar correctamente una variable de interfaz? (métodos set; get;) C#

Tags: c#, interface

Estoy intentado implementar una variable de una interfaz y no lo consigo... con las funciones funciona estupendamente pero con las variables se me queda pillado como si estuviera en un loop infinito.

```
///-------------------------------------------------- 

public interface Interface
{
    string Func();
    int id {get;set;}   
}

///-------------------------------------------------- 

public class Implemetador : Interface
{   
    public Implemetador(){}

    string Func() //-->sin problemas
    {
       return "id=";
    }

    public int id  //-->bloqueado
    {
        set{id = value;}
        get{return 55;}     
    }
}

///--------------------------------------------------

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Implemetador i = new Implemetador();                
        Console.Write(i.Func() + i.id);  
    }
}

///--------------------------------------------------
```

La forma de implentarlo la obtuve de aquí pág 16.

https://profesorezequielruizgarcia.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/poo-csharp.pdf

Creo que son apuntes de alguna universidad y no da errores al compilar así que no comprendo porqué no funciona...

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: Que error te da

Comment: no da error... simplemente no imprime nada en la consola y el programa no termina su ejecución... es como si estuviera bloqueado o un blucle infinito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este codigo crea una llamada recursiva que nunca se detendrá

```
public int id  //-->bloqueado
{
    set{id = value;}
    get{return 55;}     
}
```

La llamada a set es a la ves una llamada a la propiedad `id`

```
set{id = value;}
```

Te recomiendo cambiar la implementación de la propiedad por la siguiente:

```
public int Id  //Id con mayuscula (o cualquier otro nombre) diferente al campo id
{
    set{id = value;}
    get{return 55;}     
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Eduardo!! Ese era el problema.. ahora funciona correctamente!! :-) Saludos!!

Comment: @IvánRodríguez. Por nada estamos aquí para ayudar. Claro una recomendación deberias rectificar la linea `get{return 55;}`, pues en este caso solo te devolverá 55, cuando lo que deberia devolver es el valor almacenado, deberias  cambiarla por `get{return id;}`, así estarias devolviendo el valor que estableciste en el `get`.

Comment: Ok!!... lo del 55 era solo un test... trasteando un poco para ver si logro comprer su funcionamieto... de todas las cosas nuevas que tiene en C# con respecto al C++ yo creo que justo es esto es lo que mas me está costando comprender... todavia no le he visto una utilidad o ventaja a esta forma tan complicada de declarar una variable... En fin, vseguiré trasteando con ello. Muchas Gracias!! Un Saludo!!

Comment: @IvánRodríguez. C++ es otro paradigma de programación, pero tambien soporta POO. De manera general todos los lenguajes que soportan POO, usan  la declaración de propiedades, _PROPIEDADES_, fijate que no es lo mismo que _variable_ y en todos estos lenguajes se usan los accesores `get` y `set`, puede cambiar la sintaxis, pero basicamente es lo mismo en cualquier lenguaje.